# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tried to in Python 3.7 import the module of `rosbag` by:

```
import rosbag
```

But an exception occurs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rosbag'
```

I have installed the library by:

```
pip install pyrosbag
```

and

```
pip install bag
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `pip` is by default Python2 pip, no matter what version of Python you get when you write `python`. `pip3` is Python3 pip. You can also do `python3 -m pip install pyrosbag` to make sure it's python3's pip package that installs it.

Comment: It's not a good idea to install random packages with similar names to your actual package, you should uninstall those (and check what they are)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, then this could be a solution. First, make sure that there is a ROS version installed in your machine.

Then you need to source the ROS environment by:

```sh
# replace the `melodic` if you use another distro of ROS
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```

**Note**: Replace *melodic* by your ROS distro name if you use another distro rather than *melodic*.

Then you could import the rosbag without any other installation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your import is wrong, try:

```
import pyrosbag
```

See https://pyrosbag.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: pyrosbag is not the same package as OP is requiring.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3.X the following should do the trick:

```
pip3 install pyrosbag
```

Comment: pyrosbag is not the same package as OP is requesting. The package you suggested is actually an out of date 3rd party package that does not read the file or playback the file wich is the entire point of the rosbag library